# Meteor and Arduino - how to connect them?

Tags: meteor, arduino

i'd like to connect meteorjs and arduino. Do you know (or have tutorials etc) how to do it (for instant: steering a motor or LEDs by my browser)?

Answer (score 3):

I have wrote a blog post about this topic:

- http://julian.io/meteor-meets-arduino-and-cylon/

Also there are my packages (described there):

- https://atmospherejs.com/juliancwirko/arduino-cylon
- https://atmospherejs.com/juliancwirko/caprica

You should check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to integrate johnny-five or cylon.

- https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five
- http://cylonjs.com/

**meteorhacks:npm** package for Meteor should help : https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm/